# Find text in horizontal list and return cell value to the right

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a horizontal list that i need to pull the price from sheet1 and put it in a vertical list on sheet2.

Each price has a product code 2 colunms to the left, and on sheet2 i need a formula that finds the product code and returns the price 2 colunms to the right on sheet1

**Sheet1**

[image]

**Sheet2**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMIF()

```
=SUMIF('Sheet1'!$B$2:$L$2,A2,'Sheet1'!$D$2:$N$2)
```